# Cannot execute a stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, toad

Here is a simple example using Toad for Data Analysts 3.0.1.1734. I have full permissions on the schema JSWEENEY.

Create the table

```
CREATE TABLE JSWEENEY.TEMP_SQL
(
    SQL VARCHAR2(3000)
);
```

Create the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JSWEENEY.SP_INSERT_SQL
IS
BEGIN   
   INSERT INTO JSWEENEY.TEMP_SQL(SQL) VALUES('SELECT * FROM TEMP_SQL');
   COMMIT;
END JSWEENEY.SP_INSERT_SQL;    
/
```

Execute the procedure:

```
BEGIN
    JSWEENEY.SP_INSERT_SQL;
END;
```

The first error:

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 11:
> PLS-00905: object JSWEENEY.SP_INSERT_SQL is invalid
>
> ORA-06550: line 2, column 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Execute the procedure:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE JSWEENEY.SP_INSERT_SQL;
END;
```

The second error:

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 10:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JSWEENEY" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; immediate The symbol ":=" was substituted for "JSWEENEY" to continue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error you're getting when you run the procedure indicates that the `create procedure` statement failed with a syntax error.  If you go back and re-create the procedure, you should get a list of errors.

Comment: Thank you, but Toad indicates the procedure compiled correctly. It shows an "X" next to the procedure name if it does not compile correctly.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile the procedure you will get an error; if your client doesn't display that then you can query the `user_errors` view (or `all_errors` if you're creating it in a different schema) to see the problem. Here it will be complaining that:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/13     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:
         ;
```

It's valid to use the schema name in the `create` call; but not as part of the `end`. So if you need to specify the schema at all - which you don't if you're creating an object in your own schema, but your reference to permissions makes it sound like you aren't - then it should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JSWEENEY.SP_INSERT_SQL
IS
BEGIN   
   INSERT INTO JSWEENEY.TEMP_SQL(SQL) VALUES('SELECT * FROM TEMP_SQL');
   COMMIT;
END SP_INSERT_SQL;    
/
```

Your second error is because `execute` on its is a client command (in SQL*Plus and relations), not a PL/SQL statement. The error refers to `immediate` because PL/SQL does have an `execute immediate` statement which is used for dynamic SQL, not for making static calls to procedures. Your first syntax to run the procedure is correct, once the procedure itself is valid:

```
BEGIN
    JSWEENEY.SP_INSERT_SQL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Okay that worked. Second issue is adding a parameter.

<code>
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JSWEENEY.SP_INSERT_SQL (
       pSQL TEMP_SQL.SQL%TYPE
    )
    IS
    BEGIN   
       INSERT INTO JSWEENEY.TEMP_SQL(SQL) VALUES(pSQL');
       COMMIT;
    END SP_INSERT_SQL;    
    /
</code>

This compiles correctly

Then I run it with 

<code>
    BEGIN
        JSWEENEY.SP_INSERT_SQL('Testing Insert');
    END;
</code>
and get an error 
Object JSWEENEY.SP_INS

Comment: That won't compile correctly. You have a stray quote in `VALUES(pSQL')`. Toad should be telling you that there's a problem when your execute the `create`, and should show it as invalid. No idea why it isn't - maybe it's confused if you're working across schemas <shrug>. If you still can't get it to work you should ask a new question; the original issue is resolved, and code doesn't really work in comments. But it looks like a typo.

Comment: Looks like it also isn't happy with the column being called `SQL`, in the `pSQL TEMP_SQL.SQL%TYPE` part (or `pSQL JSWEENEY.TEMP_SQL.SQL%TYPE` if you're being consistent *8-). `SQL` is a keyword, so not a good choice as a name.

Answer (score 0):

try this edited the SQL statement.

```
create table TEMP_SQL ( col1 varchar2(100));

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_INSERT_SQL
AS
BEGIN   
   INSERT INTO TEMP_SQL SELECT * FROM TEMP_SQL;
   COMMIT;
END  SP_INSERT_SQL;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the example is supposed to illustrate inserting a literal string into the table.